# Reset Nagios LogServer admin password

Tags: nagios

I've lost my admin password to Nagios Log Server console.

How can I recovery or reset admin password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NagiosXI, you can use the following command:

`/usr/local/nagiosxi/scripts/reset_nagiosadmin_password.php --password=<newpassword>`

If you're using an older version, you need to identify the location of the `htpasswd.users` file (usually `/etc/nagios/`) and run the following command:

`htpasswd -c -b  /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin <newpassword>`

Comment: You answer is correct. Finally I have found the same solution. Unfortunatelly, elasticsearch database is broken - There was no space on disk device, and after recovery password change doesn't help. It looks like elasticsearch is not yet ready to run in real environment.